# Angular CLI(v1.7.3) ng new returning error

Tags: angular-cli

When I run

```
cd ~/projects
ng new myapp
```

I get

```
Error: Path "/app/app.module.ts" does not exist.
Path "/app/app/module.ts" does not exist.
```

My configuration is

```
Angular CLI : 1.7.3 
Node: 9.8.0
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
NVM: 0.33.8
```

I have tried various combinations of nodejs and Angular CLI but nothing I have tried works.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Some info that *could* help: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8989

Comment: I've already tried the downgrade to 1.5.3 and 1.6.3 and a variety of version up to 1.7.3. Installing the older version gives different errors i.e. dependencies like @angular-devkit/core not being available. However installing them doesn't eliminate the dependency errors.